# How do you write comments in doskey macro files?

Tags: command-line

I have inherited a beautiful mess of doskey macros, and is trying to sort them by areas of concern. So far I haven't been able to find any references that mention comments in any way, but this seems such a common scenario that I'd be surprised if it is not supported in some way..

Is there any support for comments in doskey macro files?

Or do you have any other suggestions on how to achieve a similar goal?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

[This page](http://ben.versionzero.org/wiki/Doskey_Macros) has an example of a workaround for comments in doskey.

This involves defining ;= and using it as a pseudo-comment e.g.

```
;=File listing enhancements. 
ls=dir /x $*
l=dir /x $*
ll=dir /w $*
la=dir /x /a $*

;=Remember to set the ; back to null at the end. 
;=Otherwise, you may trigger an error on load. 
;=
```

Comment: This didn't work in Windows 11 resulting in `Invalid macro definition.` error.

Comment: Oh, it actually works when you remove the leading whitespace (will edit the post to reflect that).

Comment: Editing the post didn't work with: `There are too many pending edits on Stack Overflow. Please try again later.` What I mean is eg. `;=File listing enhancements. `

Answer (score 1):

I ended up splitting related commands into separate macro files, and running a bat-script to load them all. The bat-file then contains REM comments, while the doskey macro files are entirely comment-free.

```
REM Macros that deal with the XYZ project
doskey /macrofile=XYZ_macros.txt
```

(It is like a combination of James Broadhead's and eduffy's suggestions)